# Angular: Removing <br/> tag from string (or adding it)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

EDIT: **I tagged this as Angular but forgot to explicitly post that I'm my frontend is Angular. So is there any directive or Angular sweet sauce that I can use?**

I've got text in a database field that I'm using in two different places in my actual page. The text is "Frequently/Usually".

In one part of the page I'm outputting that as part of instruction text as to what that means so I'd like the text to look like:

```
Frequently/Usually: Description of what this means.
```

Then I have a table header where I'm reusing the "Frequenty/Usually" but for spacing I need Usually on a separate line just below Frequently.

If I store this in the database as

```
Frequently/<br/>Usually
```

Then I need to strip the `<br/>`out when I display it as part of the instruction text.

Or is it possible I could store it as `Frequently/Usually`and put in the `<br/>` when I output the text in table header?

What's the best way to go about this?

I guess I could split the string on '/' then put the string back together with the `<br/>`in there.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: use css for wrapping text in header

Answer (score 0):

Use `<wbr>` instead of `<br>`. wbr is a word break opportunity, and will only break if it needs to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr

Comment: I believe `<wbr>`does not work in Internet Explorer. I have read `&#x200B;` is a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to store only plain data in database without any dependencies on presentation, and every time you are using this data, presentation layer is aware of how data should be presented.

So, you need to wrap text in **div** using **word-wrap:break-word** or if it is not possible like in your case because of "\" without spaces, your string should be preprocessed just before presenting to the user:

```
ModifiedString = OriginalString.Replace("\","\&#8203;");
```

And then you will use this string in your view:

```
<div style="width:100px;word-wrap:break-word;">
    ModifiedString
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two more options than those you listed:

- `&#x200B;` is a zero width space and will generate a line break when needed. Might be this is something you can use in your case. So: `Frequently/&#x200B;Usually`
- Set a `<span>` around the slash and style it as required, e.g. `Frequently<span class="slash">/</span>Usually` and then define some CSS along these lines:

---

```
.slash:after {
  content:"\000A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```